# Can I combine my code into some kind of "global activity"?

Tags: android

Is there any global activity on Android such that I put my code in that one activity, and it affects all activities in my project? This occurs to me because the same code is written in multiple activities like `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK`

For example here I use:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            try {
                final Intent itnt_BackServices = new Intent(this,
                        BackServices.class);
                AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                alertbox.setTitle("Touch signs");
                alertbox.setMessage("Do you want to quit!");
                alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                stopService(itnt_BackServices);
                                mPlayer.stop();

                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                alertbox.setNegativeButton("No",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                            }
                        });
                alertbox.show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I copy and paste this in each activity, and I would rather use some kind of global activity.

Comment: just to notice if you app is not a game, confirm quit is not good for the UX

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create a class that extends `Activity` and then extend the `CustomActivity` to all the `Activity` Class like this.

```
public abstract class CustomActivity extends Activity{

    public abstract void initComponents();  // you can create a abstract method
    public abstract void addListner();       // you can create a abstract method

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

         if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
              // your stuff here....
            }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now you can `extend` this `class` where you want to `extend` any class with `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

Take your first main activity write code there, and simply after that extend all the other activity with this activity.....e.g. MainActivity is your first and main activity then write this code there, and after that simply take an activity say it First then extend it with MainActivity rather than Activity...!! and That's it..........

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest extending activity as @Lalit Poptani  suggested. Since that is been said i could provide an alternative way for this to work.

You can create an interface that you implement in your activity including public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  (just to keep you a reminder you have to implement the code to your activity)

Create a global (static)  class/function that performs the onKeyDown operations.

```
public class ButtonHandler{

public static boolean handleButton(Context context,int keyCode, KeyEvent event){

..... your code here

}
```

}

and just call `return ButtonHandler.handleButton(getApplicationContext(),keycode,event)`  to your `onKeyDown` methods.

But still .. overriding activity is the best way to go. If for some reason you don't want to extend this is the way to go