# Extending class for activity

Tags: android, class, android-activity, extending

I'm totally new to Android (Java) Development and I'm so excited about it! The developers guide of Google is fantastic and I learned a lot in a small time. It even keeps me awake during the night ;)

Today I went through making menu's and there's something that I can't understand. It's about extending classes. The guide says:

> Tip: If your application contains multiple activities and some of them
>   provide the same Options Menu, consider creating an activity that
>   implements nothing except the onCreateOptionsMenu() and
>   onOptionsItemSelected() methods. Then extend this class for each
>   activity that should share the same Options Menu. This way, you have
>   to manage only one set of code for handling menu actions and each
>   descendant class inherits the menu behaviors.

The point I don't get is how to extend a class... Let say I have a **MainActivity** and a **SubActivity**. I want to have the same menu in both activities so I make a **MainMenuActivity**. How do I extend this class for both activity's?

Yes I do searched on the net but couldn't find any usable. I really want to understand it so I hope anyone can help me out with some samplecode + explanation. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Also check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618227/can-i-combine-my-code-into-some-kind-of-global-activity/7618263#7618263) just similar to what you are talking about.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What they mean is the following:

Normally you would have:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{...}
```

If you have 4-5-6... of those activities, and each of them uses the same menu code, you could just copy and paste the code 4-5-6.. times. Or you could do this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity{
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //My menu code  
    }
}
```

And use this class for your 4-5-6... Activities:

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity{...}
```

This way you don't need to copy your menu creation code into all your Activities, and moreover, you don't have to edit 4-5-6... classes to edit a small bit of creation of the menu. The menu code is now also in `MyActivity`.

---

You could also have a look [here](http://xahlee.info/java-a-day/extend.html), it explains what `extends` means.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Now I get it, it's easier than I thought!!

Answer (score 11):

It's quite simple really.

**MainMenuActivity**

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity {
   //Override or add whatever functionality you want other classes to inherit.
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends MainMenuActivity {
   //Add what is specific to MainActivity. The menu will be inherited from MainMenuActivity.
}
```

**SubActivity**

```
public class SubActivity extends MainMenuActivity {
   //Add what is specific to SubActivity. The menu will be inherited from MainMenuActivity.
}
```