# Extend Navigation Bar into another activity (no fragments)

Tags: android, navigation, extends

I read some question regarding this but all the answers are about fragments and there is question similar to this one but the answer is incomplete, I want to reuse a set of layout or codes into multiple activities, i created a baseActivity that extends into Activity with the code below.

I also read that you need to put the code in the onCreateOptionMenu but it is still not working. (the code in baseacitivty xml is working, and homepage xml is working but does not show the navigation_layout)

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageButton ibButtonHome;
    private ImageButton ibButtonFavorite;
    private ImageButton ibButtonRandomize;
    private ImageButton ibButtonHistory;
    private ImageButton ibButtonLogOut;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_layout);

    }

    View.OnClickListener Navigation = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            if (v.equals(ibButtonHome)) {
                i.setClass(getBaseContext(), HomePage.class);
            } else if (v.equals(ibButtonFavorite)) {
                i.setClass(getBaseContext(), Favorite.class);
            } else if (v.equals(ibButtonHome)) {
                i.setClass(getBaseContext(), HomePage.class);
            } else if (v.equals(ibButtonRandomize)) {
                i.setClass(getBaseContext(), Randomize.class);
            } else if (v.equals(ibButtonHistory)) {
                i.setClass(getBaseContext(), History.class);
            } else if (v.equals(ibButtonLogOut)) {
                //TODO: something code here to not crash on activity exit??
                i.setClass(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
            }

            startActivity(i);

        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        ibButtonHome = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_Home);
        ibButtonFavorite = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_favorites);
        ibButtonRandomize = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_randomize);
        ibButtonHistory = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_history);
        ibButtonLogOut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_logout);

        ibButtonFavorite.setOnClickListener(Navigation);
        ibButtonRandomize.setOnClickListener(Navigation);
        ibButtonHome.setOnClickListener(Navigation);
        ibButtonHistory.setOnClickListener(Navigation);
        ibButtonLogOut.setOnClickListener(Navigation);

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_filter_menus, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Homepage activity

```
    public class HomePage extends BaseActivity {
    private CustomAdpaterFoodFeed ExpAdapter;
    private ArrayList<FoodFeed> foodFeeds;
    private ExpandableListView ExpandList;
    //Onclick listener for the Navigation Bar

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

        ExpandList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.evFoodFeed);



        //runs the function and returns the data to foodFeeds
        foodFeeds = SetStandardGroups();

        //Adapter for ExapadableListView
        ExpAdapter = new CustomAdpaterFoodFeed(HomePage.this, foodFeeds);
        ExpandList.setAdapter(ExpAdapter);



    }

    // Dummy data method for pictures and comments
    public ArrayList<FoodFeed> SetStandardGroups() {

        String names[] = {"Geraldine", "Marielle", "Gina", "Bryan",
                "Pat", "Eugene", "Shermaine", "Kook"};

        String comments[] = {"TasteGood", "Nah", "DONT EAT HERE", "Cameroon",
                "Nice place", "chill", "woah Spain", "lalala"};

        int Images[] = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher
        };

        ArrayList<FoodFeed> list = new ArrayList<FoodFeed>();

        ArrayList<Comments> comments_list;


        for (int images : Images) {
            FoodFeed gru = new FoodFeed();
            gru.setIcon(images);

            comments_list = new ArrayList<Comments>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                Comments comments1 = new Comments();
                comments1.setName(names[j]);
                comments1.setComments(comments[j]);

                comments_list.add(comments1);
            }
            gru.setComments(comments_list);
            list.add(gru);


        }

        return list;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: only one activity's layout can be visible at a time but you can use base activity to extend the navigation drawer in other activities

Comment: you can extend the layout of the activity in the fragments because they are the part of the activity

Comment: I already extended the base activity to my other activities but it is still not working, i think i am lacking something @Awadesh

Comment: I said in my earlier comment that two activities can not be visible simultaneously as each activity has its own layout so it can not be possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8255614/extending-class-for-activity, i am trying to do this suggestion

Comment: yes I also said that it can be done for navigation drawer and action bar

Comment: I am trying to do something like  that

Comment: I have used base activity to extend the navigation drawer in other activities if you want i can post the whole code

Comment: please :)) Thank you @Awadesh

Comment: I have posted the answer if you have any doubt please ask :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Base activity to extend the navigation drawer in other activities you can follow this link , described well. it is well tested i followed the same :)

http://androiddeveloperdemo.blogspot.in/2014/08/android-navigation-drawer-with-multiple.html

You can get the same action bar in other activities by declaring in AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
 <activity
        android:name=".SettingsActivity"
        android:label="@string/activity_title"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

For different menu options define a xml file under menu folder in android studio and inflate that file in 
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) overridden method of your activty

Comment: the problem with this is I dont know how to remove the animation in the side bar, I only want the navbar to be like the instagram navbar, I am just new to android :(