# How to include common code in android

Tags: android

I am creating am android application which has 4 different activities all having a common menu. To show menu in all activities generally I need to add this code in every files.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Is there anyway that I can add this code in one single file & include to all activities?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can refer my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618227/can-i-combine-my-code-into-some-kind-of-global-activity/7618263#7618263)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create one `Main Activity` write your menu code in that activity and then `extend` other activities with Main Activity..

```
public MainActivity extends Activity 
{ 
  @Override 
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { 
   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater(); 
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu); 
   return true; 
} 

   @Override 
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
           return false; 
   }     
}
```

And some `TempActivity`

```
public TempActivity extend MainActivity
{

/......
}
```

Comment: Yes, almost everyone who make a sharing menu for all activities are do like that..

Comment: gr8. i never used that. will use from the next time. thank u. +1 for the answer and question as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
abstract class MenuHavingActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
  }
}
```

and then have your other activities extend MenuHavingActivity

edit: yeah, what user370305 said