# one menu for all tabs in tablayout?

Tags: android, menu, tabs

Begginer to Android development. I am developing a application, which have three different tabs. I want to have common menu options. Problem is when menu item is clicked nothing happens. It works when i moved them to activity for first tab.
Here is my TabActivity menu implementation.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.feedbackEmail:
                showDialog(FEEDBACK_DIALOG_ID);
                return true;
            case R.id.about:
                AboutBox.Show(this);
                return true;
            case R.id.Help:
                HelpBox.Show(this);
                return true;
            case R.id.Preferences:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.powerUsage:
                startActivity(intentPowerUsage);
                return true;
            case R.id.close:
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
                homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                Preferences.cancelNotification(this);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
```

Here is my menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/feedbackEmail"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
          android:title="@string/feedback" />
    <item android:id="@+id/Help"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
          android:title="@string/menu_help" />
    <item android:id="@+id/Preferences"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_preferences"
          android:title="@string/preferences" />
    <item android:id="@+id/about"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
          android:title="@string/menu_about" />
    <item android:id="@+id/powerUsage"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_today"
          android:title="@string/powerUsage" />
    <item android:id="@+id/close"
          android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
          android:title="@string/exit" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Could you post your menu.xml, will make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in like this,

Create an Activity named `BaseActivity` and put this Menu code in that `BaseActivity`, then extends all the `Activity` that you want to have menu. You can check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618227/can-i-combine-my-code-into-some-kind-of-global-activity/7618263#7618263) answer for further reference that overrides `onKeyDown()` for every Activity.

Comment: But i already extends all the activities with ListActivity and if i not mistake java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Comment: If you have extended all your activities with ListActivity then extend the BaseActivity with ListActivity instead of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use break statement for every case and remove return true from every case as below::

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.feedbackEmail:
                showDialog(FEEDBACK_DIALOG_ID);
                break;
            case R.id.about:
                AboutBox.Show(this);
                break;
            case R.id.Help:
                HelpBox.Show(this);
                break;
            case R.id.Preferences:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.powerUsage:
                startActivity(intentPowerUsage);
                break;
            case R.id.close:
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                homeIntent.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
                homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                Preferences.cancelNotification(this);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```