# how to use the widgets assigned in a activity in another activity?

Tags: android

I am creating an android project . In that i i got the ids from the XML file and wrote the click events in a (class or activity) . I want to use the widgets from another class without getting the id's again. like (Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);) i want to use this code in one class

But I want to use the Button btn in another class and also the click event should work.

Comment: If you need to use the same widgets which probably means you are using the same view, then why two activities are required?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use any View in more than one `Activity` you can create a class `BaseActivity` that extends Activity and include all the common Views in that Activity and then extend this `BaseActivity` to all the `Activity` in which you want to use common `views/layouts/headers/footers`. For a Pseudo code you can check my answer [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7618263/726863).